# GoDaddy domain (randomly) not resolving to GitHub Pages

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, dns-hosting, github

I have added a CNAME file to the root level of my GitHub Pages repository, which contains my domain (_____.com).

My DNS settings on the GoDaddy website look like this: [DNS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfejO.png). On the "Manage My Domains" page, it says

> ________.com is just sitting there. Put it to work.

But I just assumed since I'm manually changing the DNS settings, that its fine.

I set this all up following GitHub's instructions on their website, and going to my domain correctly shows my GitHub Pages website - sometimes. At other (seemingly random) times, a GoDaddy page will pop up: [GoDaddy Pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjx2L.png)

When this first started happening, I chalked it up to the domain being newly registered, assuming that things would fix themselves in a few days. It's been over a week now though, and sometimes my website will show up, and sometimes the GoDaddy page will show up.

I'm not sure if this is related, but resetting my internet connection or clearing my web browser cache seems to fix it sometimes, but not all the time. I've asked friends to load my domain name, and on some days they are able to see the website, on other days they see the GoDaddy page.

Should I just give it a couple more weeks and see if things start working properly? Or is it an issue with GoDaddy/GitHub? I'm completely open to switching to a different domain name registrar or website host (or both) in order to get this to work.

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry for the late response - the domain name is kristinedomingo.com

Answer (score 3):

You have *three* IP addresses registered for the apex of your domain:

```
kristinedomingo.com has address 192.30.252.153
kristinedomingo.com has address 192.30.252.154
kristinedomingo.com has address 50.63.202.41
```

Two of these belong to GitHub, and one belongs to GoDaddy. Because DNS is round-robin, about 2/3 of the time you will go to the right place, and the rest of the time you end up at GoDaddy's parking page.

To fix the problem, remove the GoDaddy IP address.

Comment: This helped me quickly and easily diagnose this exact issue, thanks a lot.